# calculate Ax=λx by vectors of eigen() and rotation of prcomp() in R

Tags: r

I learned the equation Ax=λx where x is the eigenvector and λ is the eigenvalue and I tried to prove this equation by using R, I wrote the following code:

```
x <- c(60, 35, 30, 80, 50)
y <- c(58, 68, 40, 70, 95)
z <- c(25, 50, 60, 80, 45)
dat <- cbind(x, y, z)

e <- eigen(cor(scale(dat)))
p <- prcomp(dat, scale.=TRUE)

# Ax=λx
c1 <- cor(scale(dat)) %*% p$rotation
c2 <- diag(e$values) %*% p$rotation
c3 <- p$rotation %*% diag(e$values)
```

My question is why Ax!=λx and Ax=xλ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
diag(e$values) %*% p$rotation
```

multiplies the rows of the rotation matrix with the eigenvalues, while

```
p$rotation %*% diag(e$values)
```

multiplies the columns of the rotation matrix with the eigenvalues. From the documentation `?prcomp` you can see that the rotation matrix has the eigenvectors in columns and therefore you want the second one. As a simple example try the following:

```
> matrix(1, 3, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
> diag(1:3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    0    0    3
> diag(1:3) %*% matrix(1, 3, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
> matrix(1, 3, 3) %*% diag(1:3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
```